# Pass anonymous method belonging to object as an argument- Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an object with a method, I want to pass the method as an argument to another function. However the function must know the object associated with the method (or it can't access values assigned to the object after creation).

Is there a way to this without resorting to passing the object/method as a string?
(ex not using: `window[function_name];`)

```
function My_Object(name){
    this.name = name;
}

My_Object.prototype.My_Method = function(){
     alert(this.name);
}

//This is the function that passes the method
function Runner(){
     var NewObject = new My_Object('Andre');
     test(NewObject.My_Method);//this is where it should break
}

//This is the function that receives and calls the Object's method
function test(func){
    func();
}
```

Comment: it would help if you paste some code that shows us what you want to accomplish

Comment: just pass the object itself to the function, the function can then access everything it needs. Some code samples would help give more context-specific answers.

Comment: This is totally a duplicate. My Google-fu is just letting me down.

Comment: every function has its own execution context.so when you pass just the function to a different function , it will execute on a different context and it wont be able to access name.

Comment: @Matt right, those are really hard to find.

Comment: @SebastienD. Unfortunately, this question requires the function name to be passed. Otherwise you're right, it would be a lot simpler

Comment: `test(function() { NewObject.My_Method(); })` ?

Comment: ... or `test(NewObject.My_Method.bind(NewObject));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **a anonymous function**:

```
//This is the function that passes the method
function Runner(){
     var NewObject = new My_Object('Andre');
     test(function() {
         NewObject.My_Method();
     });
}
```

or **bind your method to `NewObject`** like this:

```
//This is the function that passes the method
function Runner(){
     var NewObject = new My_Object('Andre');
     test(NewObject.My_Method.bind(NewObject));
}
```

And **if you don't change your `test` function in the future**, you can simple call the function you want to test in the `Runner` function:

```
//This is the function that passes the method
function Runner(){
     var NewObject = new My_Object('Andre');
     NewObject.My_Method(); // directly call the function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment about execution context is important here:

```
//This is the function that passes the method
function Runner(){
     var NewObject = new My_Object('Andre');
     test(NewObject.My_Method,NewObject);
}

//This is the function that receives and calls the Object's method
function test(func,ctx){
    func.apply(ctx || this);
}
```